# Facebook fetch user's profile info

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to fetch the user's profile info like name or email using their Facebook but it doesn't seem to work anymore. is it still possible 
to get another user's account info using the ID?

I get this respose using the Facebook sdk:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message
>   'Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1691918994166305' does not
>   exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not
>   support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api' in
>
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fizops.com/facebook/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:106
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fizops.com/facebook/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(210):
>   Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse))
>
> #1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fizops.com/facebook/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(255):
>   Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException() #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fizops.com/facebook/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php(82):
>   Facebook\FacebookRes in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fizops.com/facebook/vendor/facebook/graph-sdk/src/Facebook/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php
>   on line 106

Using this url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1777651498915121/?access_token=xxx|xxx
```

Response:

> {    "error": {
>         "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '1777651498915121' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing
>   permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph
>   API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
>         "type": "GraphMethodException",
>         "code": 100,
>         "fbtrace_id": "HYwXjUHaT8W"    } }

Comment: Where did you get the user id from? Is it actually an app-scoped id belonging to your app?

Comment: just use /me instead of the user id - of course with a user access token

Comment: I got the user id from Reamaze, they said I can trace it back to facebook using the graph api.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you specified the wrong user_id, I tried with the wrong user_id and the same error is obtained. You can try to understand how it works here. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer , select your Application, Get User Access Token and push Submit.

I experimented a little, and noticed that for each application there are  different user_id's and you will have such error  when you will use the user_id of another application.

Comment: I could get their profile pic using their id. but technically just really need their name and possibly the email to cross check with orders. I tried your link but gives me same errors. I tried multiple IDs. only works for my personal ID.

Comment: As far as I know, Facebook SDK does not provide such an opportunity. You can only receive data from those users who gave you permission to do so.